# Clojure cache with a cap and TTL

Tags: caching, clojure

I'm using [`clojure.core.memoize`](https://github.com/clojure/core.memoize/tree/master/docs) (which uses [`clojure.core.cache`](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache)). I want to use a [TTL cache](https://github.com/clojure/core.memoize/blob/master/docs/TTL.md) but also want to have a cap on the total cache size (as I could supply for a FIFO cache).

I know that there are all sorts of flavours of cache that combine queues, TTLs, etc. I don't necessarily want something that exotic, just a simple way to cap the collection size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the memoize functions in `clojure.core.memoize` seem to be taking an optional base cache that can be used to combine different caching strategies:

```
(require '[clojure.core [memoize :as memo] [cache :as cache]])
(def memoized-identity
  (memo/fifo
    identity
    (cache/ttl-cache-factory {} :ttl 5000)
    :fifo/threshold 32))
```

See `core.cache`'s [wiki entry on composability](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache/wiki/Composing) for more information.

Comment: That's great, thanks. Don't know why I missed that page.

Answer (score 1):

An updated usage with [clojure.core.memoize](https://github.com/clojure/core.memoize) 1.0.236

```clj
(def memoized-inc
  (memo/memoizer (fn [m] (println ::HIT m) (inc m))
                 (-> {}
                     (cache/fifo-cache-factory :threshold 32)
                     (cache/ttl-cache-factory :ttl 5000))))
```